Circular "ring" buffers onboard Network Interface Cards
In these ring buffers that NICs have, are packet descriptors (that contain things like the memory address of where that network packet will be stored in system memory, the status, and any other additional metadata) stored alongside the network packet itself? Like does each network packet get it's own corresponding packet descriptor (either Tx or Rx from what I've seen somewhere)?
I searched for answers on Google but a lot of them gave me mixed answers "ring buffers are actually stored in system memory" and others claiming that they are stored in the NIC itself

NICs stopped using (more than minimal) internal buffers when PCI came up, 30 years ago.
With PCI (or PCIe today), the NIC driver allocates host memory to be used for buffer DMA - that's why you can actually configure the size/number of buffers in the driver. Usually the buffer is structured in multiple queues by Tx, Rx, or priorities and often organized as rings.
I'm not sure what 'packet descriptors' you're referring to. The NIC (driver) obviously requires pointers to one or more buffer areas. Everything else about the buffered packets resides in that buffer.
